# Problems when viewing xtrareports toolbar in mvc c # and devExpress 16.2

Tags: c#, devexpress-mvc

Please, could you help me identify the inconvenience by showing a report?

I attach an image so you can visualize the problem

Thank you very much for your help

[toolbar xtrareport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsecg.png)

Comment: Could you add sample code and be more specific about Components and their datasource you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```html
@if (Session["reporteMovimiento"] != null)
{

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Extrato de Cobrança - Francesinha</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse in" id="collapseDiv41">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if (Session["producto"] != null)
                        {
                            @Html.Action("DocumentViewer1Partial", "CobChequesFran")
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

```html
@if (Session["reporteMovimiento"] != null)
{
@Html.DevExpress().DocumentViewer(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "DocumentViewer1";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "CobChequesFran", Action = "DocumentViewer1Partial" };
    settings.ExportRouteValues = new { Controller = "CobChequesFran", Action = "DocumentViewer1PartialExport" };
    settings.Report = (XtraReport)Model;
    settings.ToolbarMode = DocumentViewerToolbarMode.StandardToolbar;
}).GetHtml()
}
```

I use compiled views and I invoke them from a main project